# How to get the filename from a http link in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, file, sed, hyperlink

In a shell script i have a variable `$FILE_LINK`, which contains the following string:

```
http://links.twibright.com/download/links-2.13.tar.gz
```

What i need is to get the filename from the link, and store it in a different variable, so the process would look similar to this:

> 1. Set variable `$FILE_LINK`
> 2. Get the last string after the last "/", in this case 'links-2.13.tar.gz'
> 3. Store the string in a variable `$FILE_LINK_NAME`

How i could achieve that?

Comment: If using BASH use: `FILE_LINK_NAME="${FILE_LINK##*/}"`

Comment: I think if you do a search on SO, you could find at least 5 different ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using BASH use:

```
file_link='http://links.twibright.com/download/links-2.13.tar.gz'
file_link_name="${file_link##*/}"

links-2.13.tar.gz
```

Or else use `basename` (not available on OSX):

```
file_link_name=$(basename "$file_link")
```

If not use this `awk`:

```
file_link_name=$(awk -F / '{print $NF}' <<< "$file_link")
```

Or using `sed`:

```
file_link_name=$(sed 's~.*/~~' <<< "$file_link")
```

**PS:** I'm avoiding all uppercase variable names in order to avoid clash with ENV variables.

Comment: could also add `basename "$file_link"` :)

Comment: Of course :) I keep forgetting about `basename` as I am on OSX.

Comment: What do you mean `basename` not available on OSX?

Comment: `basename` utility doesn't come by default on Mac OSX.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: YMMV if the link ends in `/`, e.g. `http://google.com/whatever/`. It'd probably be good to strip any trailing `/` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
LINK=http://links.twibright.com/download/links-2.13.tar.gz
FILE=`echo $LINK | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
echo $FILE
```

The output is `links-2.13.tar.gz`

---

awk is a good tool for text processing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

`-F` set the separator

`$NF` means the last column